# Longest string with 3 characters without adjacent repeating secuences?

Tags: string, algorithm

I tried making a tree but cannot make it in time.

The longest I have found is 15: 
BCACBABCABACBABC

For example (wrong):
ababcabcab

(abcabc repeats abc. Obviously abcabc is not the only wrong thing)

Another:
aa

(a repeats)

This is a correct example (it is not wrong):
ABA

Comment: Please share more details on your tree-based approach to this problem.

Comment: Your example repeats ABC also.**ABCbABCacbacb** And then it repeats "acb" also.

Comment: All the ways to make an n lengthed tree until I found one (check each one if it works). When one is found check with length n+1. Repeat.

Comment: Sorry, without ADJACENT repeating secuences.

Comment: You still have ACB ACB repeating adjacently at the end.

Comment: Then it is wrong. Why the downvote?

Comment: How are you defining an adjacent repeating sequence? Is AA a repeating sequence, since you have A, and then A again?

Comment: Yes, updated to clarify.

Comment: "Then it is wrong. Why the downvote?"  I downvoted because you didn't explain clearly what "repeating sequence" meant, *and* your broken example prevented people from even trying to guess what you *might have* meant.

Comment: So by "adjacent" you mean immediately adjacent, it seems? So AA is a problem, but ABA is not?

Comment: See that it was literally as it is explained. An adjacent repeating secuence is a secuence that repeats and is adjacent to its repetition.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: I think this is more of a mathematics question than a programming one. For what it's worth, I suspect there's no limit on the length of these sequences. Here's one of length 400: `'abacabcacbabcabacabcacbacabacbabcabacabcacbabcabacbabcacbacabacbabcabacabcacbabcbacabacbabcabacabcacbacabacbabcabacabcbabcabacbabcacbacabacbabcabacabcacbabcabacbabcacbacabacbabcabacabcbabcabacbabcacbacabacbabcabacbcabcbabcabacabcacbabcabacabcbabcabacbabcacbacabacbabcabacabcacbabcabacbabcacbacabacbabcabacabcbabcabacbabcacbacabacbabcabacbcabcbabcabacbabcacbacabacbabcabacabcacbabcabacbabcacbacabacbab'`

Comment: I was suspecting that too. I don't see a reason there must be a maximal one. You could fairly easily write a search algorithm, but if it turns out there's no maximal string or that the maximal string is huge, it'd take a long time to run. It's an interesting question though, if there's a more efficient algorithm or an observation which makes it simpler. And to be fair, he never said anything about programming. ;)

Comment: I don't have time to think about a full solution, but here're a few thoughts. Say that you've got a string of `n` characters which is valid (no repetitions, as defined): `X` (`U`, `V`, `X` and `Y` will stand for however many characters we want them to, and their lowercase versions will represent the number of characters -- here, `X` is `n` characters, so `x=n`). Say, without loss of generality, that the first character is an `A`: `A X` (here, `x=n-1` characters). Then obviously you can't add an `A` to the left, or you'd have a repetition: `A AX`. If you want to add a `B` to the left, you'd

Comment: have to have the following pattern in order for it to HAVE a repetition: `B AXBAXY`, where `1+x + 2+x + y = n`. So assuming you've got such a pattern, you'd want to put a `C` on the left instead of that `B`, which would yield: `C AXBAXY`. However, you're going to have to then deal with the possibility of also having the following pattern in those characters: `C AUCAUV`, where again, `1+u + 2+u + v = n`. You'll have to show that the overlap of `AXBAXY` and `AUCAUV` means one or the other pattern can't exist... if that's clear. Sorry I can't explain more, I've gotta run!

Comment: (Note in that last thing, `u != x` and `v != y`.)

Comment: What do you want exactly? A string of specific length? A proof that the maximal length is equal to something (or that it's not bounded)?

Comment: Google suggestion: "squarefree ternary words". And indeed there are arbitrarily long ones. See [this](http://oeis.org/A006156) OEIS sequence and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_word) Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark Dickinson pointed out, it is infinite. It was proved by Axel Thue. It is a famous set of words called "Square-free Ternary Words".

Here is an example:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_word#Examples